# How to boot directly into a VirtualBox image?

Tags: virtualbox

I have a running setup as following:

- Native OS: Windows 7 64bit, 3 Partitions:

  - c: (System)
  - d: (FAT32, here is my vdi file)
  - e: (unformatted)
- VirtualBox: Fedora 14 running off the vdi file on drive d.

Usually this setup is great for me, but sometimes I’d like to run Linux natively, and not inside VirtualBox.

Is there a way to boot **directly** into the VDI file without the Windows overhead? E.g. using a USB stick with some modified Linux Kernel / GRUB that can mount the vdi file directly as "/"?

Or copy the contents of my VDI file to the empty partition and somehow use this from VirtualBox (when booting into Windows) AND directly booting into Linux?

Hope to get some hints or even “how to”s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got a good answer on a sister site:
https://serverfault.com/questions/221516/howto-boot-directly-into-a-virtualbox-image

Comment: well how about that, never mind for my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is not possible. You may be able to boot Linux off a USB (with the Linux version of VB installed) and then use the .vdi stored on the D:\ drive.

Comment: its possible I just forget how.